# i use Admob and i recive Violation of Usage of Android Advertising ID policy and section 4.8

Tags: javascript, java, android

I've just received this message from Google Play but I'm not collecting the Advertising ID.

Violation of Usage of Android Advertising ID policy and section 4.8 of the Developer Distribution Agreement

i use this dependencies

```
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:15.0.0'
```

i noticed some permission added automatically, i didn't add it in Androidmanifest.xml

So i added

```
uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" tools:node="remove"
uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" tools:node="remove"
```

to my Androidmanifest.xml but it seams that stop google admob.

how i fix this issue ?